# Sending Pictures like WhatsApp

Tags: android, chat, image-uploading, file-transfer

I have made a chatting application. I want to add **photo/file sharing** concept in my application same as WhatsApp. I have made the app using `Xmpp/Openfire` and current now I am using this function for photo sharing, but it is not all reliable :

```
public void sendFile(final String path, final String receiver) {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
                .getInstanceFor(connection);

                if (sdm == null)
                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

                // Create the file transfer manager
                FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(
                        connection);
                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);

                // Create the outgoing file transfer
                OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager
                .createOutgoingFileTransfer(receiver + "/Smack");

                System.out.println("Receiver of the file is "+receiver+"/smack");


                Log.i("transfere file", "outgoingfiletransfer is created");

                try {

                    OutgoingFileTransfer.setResponseTimeout(30000);
                    transfer.sendFile(new File(path), "Description");
                    Log.i("transfere file", "sending file");
                    while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Log.i("transfere file", "sending file status "
                                    + transfer.getStatus() + "progress: "
                                    + transfer.getProgress());
                            if (transfer.getStatus() == Status.error) {
                                Log.i("transfere file", "Errorrr isss: "
                                        + transfer.getError());
                                transfer.cancel();
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.i("transfere file", "sending file done");
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
```

I want to do it same as WhatsApp or any other good means. Please suggest a good solution

Thanks

Comment: Can you please ellaborate `its not reliable`?

Comment: Also did you check [this link](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/41391)? The post by sherif works!

Comment: @BomberMan Yes I am using this link only provided by sherif. Sometimes the photos reach to the receiver and sometimes not. It is not at all reliable

Comment: @BomberMan. Also when I use this method provied by sherif, I do connect it to the connection at the time of login. It sends multiple presence packets ( 6-7) un neccessarily. My app is handling those packets at some other instance.
Meanwhile it is creating a big problem to me.
Any other solution please???

Comment: @BomberMan I have one more problem regarding XMPP. Can I add a member in just two steps.i.e when one person sends a request to some other person. It should add on Allow and Reject on Reject.
Current now I am managing it sending four sets of subscribe/subscribed packets - very irritating

Comment: @GauravArora Have you find any solution to ur problem ?

Comment: @Hunt No Hunt.I have not found any good way to do the same